# Twilio with Django for OTP

Tags: python, django, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to verify phonenumbers and send an otp to them in django but I get this error 400 Client Error: BAD REQUEST for url: https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACb72b622666f57139034b55062d3bbe9c/Messages.json Please what could I be doing wrong.

THe message from twilio is:

```
{"first_page_uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACb72b622666f57139034b55062d3bbe9c/Messages.json?PageSize=50&Page=0", "end": 0, "previous_page_uri": null, "messages": [], "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACb72b622666f57139034b55062d3bbe9c/Messages.json?PageSize=50&Page=0", "page_size": 50, "start": 0, "next_page_uri": null, "page": 0}
```

This is my register function in view.py

```
def otp_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
            if user.id:
                user.twiliosmsdevice_set.create(name='SMS', number=phone_number)
                device = user.twiliosmsdevice_set.get()
                device.generate_challenge()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/Nittanfund/verify')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    context = {}
    context.update(request)
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'signup.html', context)
```

Comment: you'll have to show us what you're actually doing otherwise there's no way we can answer this. where's your code querying the twillio API?

Comment: also twillio sends back a JSON document in all their responses, with an error code. What the value of "code'?

Comment: I have edited it, the error code is a 400

Comment: Which line of the code you're showing is producing the twillio request? And 400 is the status, not the error code from Twillio (their codes are between 10000 and 99999). And where do you actually see the 400 BAD REQUEST error? Is it the `generate_challenge()`? Then show us the code for `generate_challenge()`.